# Accessing rows outside of window while aggregating in Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

In short, in the example below I want to pin 'b to be the value in the row that the result will appear in.

```
Given:
    a,b
    1,2
    4,6
    3,7 ==> 'special would be: (1-7 + 4-7 + 3-7) == -13 in this row

    val baseWin = Window.partitionBy("something_I_forgot").orderBy("whatever")
    val sumWin = baseWin.rowsBetween(-2, 0)

    frame.withColumn("special",sum( 'a - 'b ).over(win)  )
```

Or another way to think of it is I want to close over the row when I calculate the sum so that I can pass in the value  of 'b (in this case 7)

*** Update ***
Here is what I want to accomplish as an UDF. In short, I used a foldLeft.

```
  def mad(field : Column, numPeriods : Integer) : Column = {

    val baseWin = Window.partitionBy("exchange","symbol").orderBy("datetime")
    val win = baseWin.rowsBetween(numPeriods + 1, 0)


    val subFunc: (Seq[Double],Int) => Double = { (input: Seq[Double], numPeriods : Int) => {
      val agg = grizzled.math.stats.mean(input: _*)
      val fooBar = (1.0 / -numPeriods)*input.foldLeft(0.0)( (a,b) => a + Math.abs((b-agg)) )
      fooBar
    } }

    val myUdf = udf( subFunc )
    myUdf(collect_list(field.cast(DoubleType)).over(win),lit(numPeriods))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, I think you can refactor your logic a bit to achieve it. The way you have it right now, you're probably getting "-7" instead of -13.

For the "special" column, (1-7 + 4-7 + 3-7), you can calculate it like (sum(a) - count(*) * b):

```
dfA.withColumn("special",sum('a).over(win) - count("*").over(win) * 'b)
```

Comment: That's an interesting refactor.. I don't immediately see why that gives the correct answer. Also, my example was a toy problem to illustrate the goal, so it doesn't apply in this case. The actual formula I want to do is Sum( abs('a-'b)) Where 'b is the specific row value above.. (Technically the last value in the window)

Comment: The thing is that when it's insde the window, like in "sum('a - 'b).over(win), the value of "b" will not be fix, it will change per every row. That's why I put "b" outside any window calculations. If you want the abs, I think you can just wrap the expression in the withColumn.

dfA.withColumn("special", abs(sum('a).over(win) - count("*").over(win) * 'b))